# jQuery nested loop nextUntil selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, nested-loops, nextuntil

So I basically have the following files and html document

```
jQuery(function () {
jQuery(".jx_form_Annuairecommunal").click(function () {
    jQuery(this).nextUntil().find('.level3').slideToggle(300);
    return false;
});
});
```

my problem is that im not being able to stop the accordion effect to the next .level0.level2

My nextUntil() function doesnt end where desired and so it expands the whole accordion with all .level3 open

Thx for ur helpful answers in advance

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique (refering to your jsFiddle)

Comment: Maybe you wanted `jQuery(this).nextUntil('div.level3').slideToggle(300);` ?
This will get all elements next to current untill div with class 'level3'

Comment: A. Wolff I have unique IDs and Vit Kos ur method toggles my .level2 without showing any .level3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".jx_form_Annuairecommunal").click(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil('.jx_form_Annuairecommunal:has(.level0 .level2)').find('.level3').slideToggle(300);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aJGQy/)

Comment: Arun P Johny ur the boss Thx a lot !